# Increasing text size in top left of viewport

Tags: interface, customization

I found the text size a bit hard to read as my screen is realtively small, so I managed find 
Edit/Preferences/Themes/Text Style where I could increase to 13 points from the default of 11 or so.
This was great for editors, menues, widgets etc.

However, the text in the top left corner of the active view remains at the default size. Does anyone know how to increase that font size too? Thanks

Best regards

Trevor